# How to traverse in 2D matrix not row or column wise but diagonally filling all the coordinates

Tags: c, loops, matrix, dynamic-programming

[image]

I was trying to solve a `dp` question and got struck here during tabulation as through normal method this matrix will be filled row wise or column wise, but I needed values diagonally, instead of row wise or column wise. Can you provide a proper for loop for this.

Comment: Doesn't seem that hard. Do the first one starting at 0,0, then move right as long as any are left and do that one, then move down from 0,0 and start there, and then do that until you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Like any array, when moving through a two-dimensional array you must keep your indices greater than or equal to zero, and less than their maximum respective dimension.

It might help to think in terms of cardinal/ordinal directions mapped as Cartesian coordinates<sup>1</sup>. Moving *south-east* is the application of `(+1, +1)` to your current position (*origin*, `(y, x)`), moving *__-west* is `(0, -1)`, *north-__* is `(-1, 0)` and so on.

(<sup>1</sup>*C deals in row-major order, so the typical `(x, y)` gets inverted for logical array access (`array2D[y][x]`). While this lines up with the spoken order for each ordinal direction, the example below is written in terms of row & column position to avoid this confusion.*)

This example assumes you want to start in the *top-right*, moving towards the *bottom-left*, filling diagonals from *top-left* to *bottom-right* along the way (*purple* -> *red*, and so on, following the arrows in the provided image).

```
#include <stdio.h>

static unsigned diagonal(
        size_t r, size_t c,
        size_t rows, size_t cols,
        unsigned data[rows][cols],
        unsigned value)
{
    while (r < rows && c < cols)
        data[r++][c++] = value++;

    return value;
}

static void fill(size_t rows, size_t cols, unsigned data[rows][cols])
{
    unsigned value = 1;

    for (size_t c = cols; c-- > 0; )
        value = diagonal(0, c, rows, cols, data, value);

    for (size_t r = 1; r < rows; r++)
        value = diagonal(r, 0, rows, cols, data, value);
}

#define ROWS 5
#define COLS 5
int main(void)
{
    unsigned data[ROWS][COLS] = { 0 };

    fill(ROWS, COLS, data);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            printf("%3u ", data[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

```
 11   7   4   2   1 
 16  12   8   5   3 
 20  17  13   9   6 
 23  21  18  14  10 
 25  24  22  19  15
```

---

If you would rather start at `0, 0`, filling in the *top-right* then the *bottom-left*, swap

```
for (size_t c = cols; c-- > 0; )
```

for

```
for (size_t c = 0; c < cols; c++)
```

which yields:

```
  1   6  10  13  15 
 16   2   7  11  14 
 20  17   3   8  12 
 23  21  18   4   9 
 25  24  22  19   5
```

---

Or change both loops to

```
for (size_t r = rows; r-- > 0; )
    value = diagonal(r, 0, rows, cols, data, value);

for (size_t c = 1; c < cols; c++)
    value = diagonal(0, c, rows, cols, data, value);
```

to get

```
 11  16  20  23  25 
  7  12  17  21  24 
  4   8  13  18  22 
  2   5   9  14  19 
  1   3   6  10  15
```

---

Or change both functions,

```
static unsigned diagonal(
        size_t r, size_t c,
        size_t rows, size_t cols,
        unsigned data[rows][cols],
        unsigned value)
{
    while (r > 0 && c > 0)
        data[--r][--c] = value++;

    return value;
}

static void fill(size_t rows, size_t cols, unsigned data[rows][cols])
{
    unsigned value = 1;

    for (size_t c = 1; c <= cols; c++)
        value = diagonal(rows, c, rows, cols, data, value);

    for (size_t r = rows; r-- > 0; )
        value = diagonal(r, cols, rows, cols, data, value);
}
```

for

```
 15  19  22  24  25 
 10  14  18  21  23 
  6   9  13  17  20 
  3   5   8  12  16 
  1   2   4   7  11
```

---

Or

```
static unsigned diagonal(
        size_t r, size_t c,
        size_t rows, size_t cols,
        unsigned data[rows][cols],
        unsigned value)
{
    while (r > 0 && c < cols)
        data[--r][c++] = value++;

    return value;
}

static void fill(size_t rows, size_t cols, unsigned data[rows][cols])
{
    unsigned value = 1;


    for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        value = diagonal(r, 0, rows, cols, data, value);

    for (size_t c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        value = diagonal(rows, c, rows, cols, data, value);
}
```

for

```
  1   3   6  10  15 
  2   5   9  14  19 
  4   8  13  18  22 
  7  12  17  21  24 
 11  16  20  23  25
```

---

All of these examples follow two main steps:

- Exhaust all (*m*) origins along one edge, then
- exhaust *n-1* origins along a different (untouched) edge.

From any given origin, iteratively apply a (diagonal) movement, for as long as it remains in-bounds.

Again, the various changes to `r` and `c` for `data[r][c]` reflect the cardinal/ordinal directions mentioned earlier, i.e., `data[--r][c++]` moves *north-east* (with the differences in postfix and prefix operators being mainly used to stay in-bounds with respect to zero by starting slightly offset at times).

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate the cells in the diagonal order using a couple of functions that compute the next cell coordinates:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void down_right_diagonal_start(size_t *row, size_t *col, size_t rows, size_t cols) {
    *col = cols - 1;
    *row = 0;
}

int down_right_diagonal_next(size_t *row, size_t *col, size_t rows, size_t cols) {
    *row += 1;
    *col += 1;
    if (*col >= cols || *row >= rows) {
        if (*col >= *row + 1) {
            *col -= *row + 1;
            *row = 0;
        } else {
            *row = *row + 1 - *col;
            *col = 0;
            if (*row >= rows) {
                *col = cols - 1;
                *row = 0;
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

enum { ROWS = 5, COLS = 5 };

int main(void) {
    int mat[ROWS][COLS];

    size_t col, row;
    int value = 1;

    down_right_diagonal_start(&row, &col, ROWS, COLS);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ROWS * COLS; i++) {
        mat[row][col] = value++;
        down_right_diagonal_next(&row, &col, ROWS, COLS);
    }
    for (row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < ROWS; col++) {
            printf("%2d ", mat[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
11  7  4  2  1
16 12  8  5  3
20 17 13  9  6
23 21 18 14 10
25 24 22 19 15
```

Other walks through the matrix can be implemented as different functions:

```
void row_wise_start(size_t *row, size_t *col, size_t rows, size_t cols) {
    *col = 0;
    *row = 0;
}

int row_wise_next(size_t *row, size_t *col, size_t rows, size_t cols) {
    *col += 1;
    if (*col >= cols) {
        *col = 0;
        *row += 1;
        if (*row >= rows) {
            *row = 0;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void column_wise_start(size_t *row, size_t *col, size_t rows, size_t cols) {
    *col = 0;
    *row = 0;
}

int column_wise_next(size_t *row, size_t *col, size_t rows, size_t cols) {
    *row += 1;
    if (*row >= rows) {
        *row = 0;
        *col += 1;
        if (*col >= cols) {
            *col = 0;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```